# Is signing a transaction using a meta mask an essential feature of the NFT marketplace?

Tags: ether, metamask, sendsignedtransaction

I was recently tasked with creating an NFT marketplace at the company.

However, users who use our platform are not used to using meta-masks.

Colleagues fear that having customers sign in to transactions will increase barriers to entry.

However, I understand that most marketplaces must go through signing transactions.

Is it essential to have a user sign in to a transaction?

If so, I would appreciate it if you could explain it with the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer : yes ,it is essential to have user sign a transaction.

Assuming the said marketplace can trade NFTs, so to transfer NFTs and ether, one needs to sign the transaction authorizing the transfer.
Also most market place require a user authentication, in web3 it is mostly done by signing a message.

Opensea and rarible does this by integrating the metamask and having the metmask sign the transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have another question. In the contract currently in production, the seller registers the price, the contract address where the NFT was issued, and the tokenId. 

The contract receives an approval from the seller to send the token to the buyer. 

The purchase amount has been made to be sent directly by the current buyer. 

In such a case, should we receive the approve so that we can send the buyer's ETH directly?

Comment: where the users will be able see their NFT collection?

Comment: We have polling process that catch event. And server serves data from database.

Comment: oh that is cool

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it is an essential feature. It just adds more credibility to the marketplace

In one use case, imagine a user uploads some unsafe images to the website so you might want to add a ban functionality. because you know the address is verified, you can be sure you are banning the correct user.

Comment: Thank you for your input. My colleagues and I agree with you. So we decided to put it off our implementation priorities :-)

Comment: @Primrose In one use case, imagine a user uploads some unsafe images to the website so you might want to add a ban functionality. because you know the address is verified, you can be sure you are banning the correct user.